# How can I embed videos with puremotion?

Tags: html, video, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I would like to embed videos from external URL without ads.
I found puremotion Chrome extension can do this, but I don't know how can I request token.
http://www.thepuremotion.com/

I change the video url in the code , but I can't find the token.

```html
<puremotion style="display:none" data-token="_YOUR_PERSONAL_TOKEN_" data-loader="iframe" data-width="728" data-height="335"></puremotion>
<iframe src="https://openload.co/embed/QinW1lCVdvg/take.the.ball.pass.the.ball.2018.dvdrip.x264-ghouls.mkv" width="728" height="335" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The iframe works good, but the puremotion section do nothing.

Comment: It works only when their extension is installed. They don't provide a public API so its their own token in that extension. If you want to use that in your own extension without asking permission of the site owners, it'll be hacking, I guess.

Comment: I installed the extension, but ads pops up as before.